# AngularJs authorization layout

Tags: angularjs, layout, angular-ui-router, asp.net-identity, angular-services

I am building a large application with Web API and AngularJs. I built the secure web api with authentication and claim-based authorizations. One requirement is that different users can view different modules on the same template.

I am new to AngularJs. I did the authentication in client side with the tokens. Also, in web api, I created a service to get all the permission given a user id. The response is a list of resource(contoller)/action(method) pairs. How do I implement the correct layout based on authorization rules on client side? Does that solely rely on web api permissions response and show/hide (ng-hide/ng-show) content based on the permissions?

Is this a good approach? What other modules/directives do I need to look into? Such as the loader for not loading the nested route until user request the parent route.

To add complexity, this site also need to work in bi-lingual. I think ng-translate. I mentioned this because it may open up another discussion on whether this may favor MVC instead of AngularJs. But the preference is Angular if the above two problem can be resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the authentication & authorisation & validation should be done server-side. You can adjust the user interface based on the roles/claims the server *tells* the browser the current user has.

One way to do this is to create something like a roles/userprofile controller, which will respond with a list of roles the current user has. On the client side you’ll probably want something you can inject everywhere, so you’re able to determine user interface behaviour.

```
myApp.factory(‘myUser’, function(Roles, $q) {

  // Create a promise to inform other folks when we’re done.
  var defer = $q.defer();

    // For this example I’m using ngResource

    Role.query({
        /*
            No params — let the server figure out who you ‘really’ are.
            Depending on WebApi configuration this might just be 
            as simple as this.User (in context of the controller).
        */ 
    }, function(roles) {

        var user = {
            roles: roles,
            isInRole: function(role) {
                return user.roles.indexOf(role) !== -1;
            }
        };

        defer.resolve(user);
    });

    return defer;

});
```

Because the `factory` above is returning a promise we can enforce that `myUser` is resolved before a certain route/controller instance is created. One little trick I use is to gather all my route definitions in one object, loop through them with an `angular.forEach` and add a `resolve.myUser` property to each of them. You can use this to pre-load/initialize other stuff too.

Now inject the `myUser` anywhere you like:

```
myApp.controller(‘MyController’, function($scope, myUser) {
  // Expose it on the current scope
  $scope.myUser = myUser;
});
```

… and in your markup …

```
<div class=“my-content-thingy”>
  <p>Lorem del ipsum …</p>
  <button class=“btn” ng-if=“myUser.isInRole(‘content-editor’)”></button>
</div>
```

Note: You’ll probably want to use `ng-if` and not `ng-show`; the latter keeps the element in the DOM.

Just keep in mind that you don’t authenticate *anything* on the client side; that all done server side. A simple way is to place [Authorize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) attributes on the appropriate controller actions.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

A proper approach is to build AngularJS routing configuration as per Authorization on the server. This should be build just after the user is authorized and before the AngularJS app is initialized. That way the authorized user sees a "complete" app based on his roles etc. Using ng-show/ng-hide is not a good way to do it. Also each view should be doing only one thing. So load separate views based on the task that needs to be completed.

Regarding multi language support, this is independent of Authorization. Some time ago, I wrote a custom AngularJS filter that used the jQuery i18next plugin. It was a pretty simple implementation.

However you can now use https://github.com/i18next/ng-i18next

Comment: NO. I am saying initialize your AngularJS app *** after *** server side authorization and based on the views that the user will be able to access. That way there will be no logic needed to show / hide views from the user based on access.

Another way to look at it is 2 users with different roles requesting your app will see 2 different Angular application configurations based on their settings.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are suggesting two things 1. add a client-side security to secure the route on top of server side 2. instead of static layout and show/hide. build the view based on the permission from server? Where can I learn more for that approach #2? And if I don't do #1, server / web service will still stop the hacker right?

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry for misunderstanding the problem).

I think that using ng-hide/show is not much of a problem. At the end of the day, the user does not have access to the data. I think it should rely on the api permissions + show/hide of presentation. Depends on the complexity you want... You can use MVC with angularjs since it's a large application.

Comment: Not sure if this answers the question of layout based on authorization. I think I took care of the server side.